# php CRUD passing parameters

Tags: php, mysql, ezsql

I'm working on a php service.
I'd like to pass an object with the parameters to use in the "where" clause and also the "order" and "limit" params.

I'm wondering whether there is a standard way/library to make up the query based on the parameters given, or whether I'll need to roll one.

I'm using ezsql to connect to mysql.

Any pointers, much appreciated.

Comment: look on ORM like doctrine, propel : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing one yourself shouldn't be too hard. If you don't want to do so (DRY, right?), you may check out sites like [phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/) or use an abstraction layer from [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) (take a look at its [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html) if it is what you need)

Comment: thanks, Yeah I was just looking for something light to tide me over as it won't run for long. Doubt, I'll go with a orm. I just want to parse the object and create a few simple statements.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion if you would like to use already existing code: Zend Framework has a "query builder", Zend_Db_Select.

This does not require the whole Zend Framework, but it does have some depedencies you will have to include.

Documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html